# Asciidoc formatting options for semi-tabular data

Tags: text-formatting, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a query regarding how to layout some semi-tabular data in Asciidoc.

The verbatim Asciidoc I currently have is this, including some framing regular text from the surrounding narrative (it's from a section about Java GC, using a very simplified case study):

```
The heap parameters are set up as shown, and we assume that they do not change over time. 
Of course a real application would normally have a dynamically resizing heap, but this 
example is to illustrate a simple case study.

----
Overall heap size:   2G

Old generation:    1.5G

Young generation:  500M
        Eden:      400M
        S1:         50M
        S2:         50M
----

After the application has reached its steady state, the following GC metrics 
are observed:

----
Allocation rate: 100M/s
Young GC time:      0ms
Full GC time:     100ms
Object lifetime:  200ms
----

So at steady state, a young GC will occur every 4 seconds.
```

My question is this: Is this the only way to lay this out? What other methods are there? I am a reasonably proficient Asciidoc user, but keep stumbling upon new features, which makes me think that perhaps there is an alternative layout approach I could take.

Comment: Which toolchain do you use? Gradle based?

Comment: Hi - not sure why the toolchain matters, but the primary target is Atlas and I use AsciidocFX as my development env.

Comment: I ask because with gradle, it is easy to write an extension for asciidoc...

Comment: Thanks @rdmueller - good catch. In this case, extensions are definitely not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to format your data in a nice way, you can format the data as table. Specify 'delimiter separated' (`dsv`) as format and you will get a nice looking table.

In addition, you can specify the separator to make sure that only the `:` is used as such (second example):

```
The heap parameters are set up as shown, and we assume that they do not change over time. 
Of course a real application would normally have a dynamically resizing heap, but this 
example is to illustrate a simple case study.

[format="dsv"]
|====
Overall heap size:   2G

Old generation:    1.5G

Young generation:  500M
        Eden:      400M
        S1:         50M
        S2:         50M
|====

After the application has reached its steady state, the following GC metrics 
are observed:

[format="dsv",separator=":"]
|====
Allocation rate: 100M/s
Young GC time:      0ms
Full GC time:     100ms
Object lifetime:  200ms
|====

So at steady state, a young GC will occur every 4 seconds.
```

This lets you also specify alignment, width and other cell attributes in the properties of the table: http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/chunked/ch23.html

Is this what you where looking for?